# Display results on GUI python not console

Tags: python, user-interface, printing, console, chatbot

I have some scripts written containing a handful of functions to create a Chatbot
The result is shown in console. I want to change the code in order to print results on GUI not console. I'm a beginner in python - Can anyone help me?

Here is the Code

```
import random
import datetime
import webbrowser
import pyttsx3
import wikipedia
from pygame import mixer
import speech_recognition as sr
from speech_recognition.__main__ import r, audio
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
engine.setProperty('volume', 10.0)
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')

engine.setProperty('rate', rate - 25)

greetings = ['hey there', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hai', 'hey!', 'hey']
question = ['How are you?', 'How are you doing?']
responses = ['Okay', "I'm fine"]
var1 = ['who made you', 'who created you']
var2 = ['I_was_created_by_Edward_right_in_his_computer.', 'Edward', 
'Some_guy_whom_i_never_got_to_know.']
var3 = ['what time is it', 'what is the time', 'time']
var4 = ['who are you', 'what is you name']
cmd1 = ['open browser', 'open google']
cmd2 = ['play music', 'play songs', 'play a song', 'open music player']
cmd3 = ['tell a joke', 'tell me a joke', 'say something funny', 'tell something funny']
jokes = ['Can a kangaroo jump higher than a house? Of course, a house doesn’t jump at all.', 'My dog 
used to chase people on a bike a lot. It got so bad, finally I had to take his bike away.', 'Doctor: 
Im sorry but you suffer from a terminal illness and have only 10 to live.Patient: What do you mean, 
10? 10 what? Months? Weeks?!"Doctor: Nine.']
cmd4 = ['open youtube', 'i want to watch a video']
cmd5 = ['tell me the weather', 'weather', 'what about the weather']
cmd6 = ['exit', 'close', 'goodbye', 'nothing']
cmd7 = ['what is your color', 'what is your colour', 'your color', 'your color?']
colrep = ['Right now its rainbow', 'Right now its transparent', 'Right now its non chromatic']
cmd8 = ['what is you favourite colour', 'what is your favourite color']
cmd9 = ['thank you']

repfr9 = ['youre welcome', 'glad i could help you']

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Tell me something:")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            print("You said:- " + r.recognize_google(audio))
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Could not understand audio")
            engine.say('I didnt get that. Rerun the code')

            engine.runAndWait()
    if r.recognize_google(audio) in greetings:
        random_greeting = random.choice(greetings)
        print(random_greeting)
        engine.say(random_greeting)
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in question:
        engine.say('I am fine')
        engine.runAndWait()
        print('I am fine')
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in var1:
        engine.say('I was made by edward')
        engine.runAndWait()
        reply = random.choice(var2)
        print(reply)
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd9:
        print(random.choice(repfr9))
        engine.say(random.choice(repfr9))
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd7:
        print(random.choice(colrep))
        engine.say(random.choice(colrep))
        engine.runAndWait()
        print('It keeps changing every micro second')
        engine.say('It keeps changing every micro second')
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd8:
        print(random.choice(colrep))
        engine.say(random.choice(colrep))
        engine.runAndWait()
        print('It keeps changing every micro second')
        engine.say('It keeps changing every micro second')
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd2:
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load("song.wav")
        mixer.music.play()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in var4:
        engine.say('I am a bot, silly')
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd4:
        webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com')
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd6:
        print('see you later')
        engine.say('see you later')
        engine.runAndWait()
        exit()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd5:
        owm = pyowm.OWM('YOUR_API_KEY')
        observation = owm.weather_at_place('Bangalore, IN')
        observation_list = owm.weather_around_coords(12.972442, 77.580643)
        w = observation.get_weather()
        w.get_wind()
        w.get_humidity()
        w.get_temperature('celsius')
        print(w)
        print(w.get_wind())
        print(w.get_humidity())
        print(w.get_temperature('celsius'))
        engine.say(w.get_wind())
        engine.runAndWait()
        engine.say('humidity')
        engine.runAndWait()
        engine.say(w.get_humidity())
        engine.runAndWait()
        engine.say('temperature')
        engine.runAndWait()
        engine.say(w.get_temperature('celsius'))
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in var3:

        print("Current date and time : ")
        print(now.strftime("The time is %H:%M"))
        engine.say(now.strftime("The time is %H:%M"))
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd1:
        webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
    elif r.recognize_google(audio) in cmd3:
        jokrep = random.choice(jokes)
        engine.say(jokrep)
        engine.runAndWait()
    else:
        engine.say("please wait")
        engine.runAndWait()
        print(wikipedia.summary(r.recognize_google(audio)))
        engine.say(wikipedia.summary(r.recognize_google(audio)))
        engine.runAndWait()
        userInput3 = input("or else search in google")
        webbrowser.open_new('www.google.com/search?q=' + userInput3)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Instead of using ```print()```, use a function that directs the string to your output console?

Comment: It seems to me is that what you want to do is to decide about some GUI library/module and implement the GUI in it. Let you check if a tutorial of one of these libraries gives you an answer https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming . Another option is to implement a web server in python and generate HTML pages for a web browser.  See for example this https://realpython.com/pysimplegui-python/#getting-started-with-pysimplegui